# Pop-up when a pdf is download in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I get a pop-up "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?" in IE11 when a pdf is downloaded.

With the code below in angularts the correct pop-up is opened "Do you want to open or save the file"? But also "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?"

```
const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({
  // 'Cache-Control': 'private',
  // 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename = ' + filename,
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
});

const requestOptions = {
  headers: headerOptions,
  responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'
};

this.http
  .post(
    `${this.url}?id=${id}&datasource=${datasource}&device=${device}&browser=${browser}&link=${link}`,
    dataObj,
    requestOptions
  )
  .catch(error => { 
    return this.clickHandlerError(error);
  })
  .pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      const blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
      });

      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((result: any) => {});
```

I expect to have just the correct pop-up to open or save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a client side error message letting the user know that this action will cause an application to open on the user's system.  If you want this to stop then you'll need to configure the client machine not the web application.

I suggest you to check your IE options and disable this prompt.

If issue persist than you can reset your IE application can help to fix this issue.